# mysql ordering question using date and status field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Need ideas on the most efficient way to order some items/events based on date and by status.

Currently I have the following query.

```
select tevent.ID, tevent.ename, e_dates.edate, tevent.status, tevent.eactive  from tevent 
LEFT JOIN e_dates on tevent.ID=e_dates.EID) Where tevent.status <> 'delete' and tevent.eactive ='Y'  group by tevent.id order 
by (case when tevent.status = 'closed' and e_dates.edate >= curdate() then 0 
else 1 end), edates.edate desc
```

I used a case but it ordered the status, then by date, which confuses people.

Below is the output

```
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
| ID |Edate           | Ename   | Status  | 
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
|  2  | 2018-09-21    | Event2  | Closed  |
|  5  | 2018-09-15    | Event5  | Closed  | 
|  3  | 2018-12-12    | Event3  | Open    |
|  6  | 2018-10-25    | Event6  | Approved|
|  4  | 2018-10-25    | Event4  | Open    |
|  7  | 2018-10-15    | Event7  | Pending |
|  10 | 2018-10-01    | Event10 | Open    |
|  1  | 2018-09-30    | Event1  | Open    |
|  4  | 2018-09-30    | Event4  | Open    |
|  8  | 2018-09-01    | Event8  | Closed  |
|  11 | 2018-08-25    | Event11 | Closed  |
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
```

**EDITED:**
What I'm trying to accomplish is to list the closed events in which the event date is before the date of the event stay on top.  IE (ID 2 and ID 5)

But want the event status that are OPEN, APPROVED, PENDING be listed in chronological order by ASC.

and closed event in which the event date (edate) is after the current date (now()) listed at the bottom

For example:

```
   +----+--------------+-----+-----------+
    | ID |Edate           | Ename   | Status  | 
    +----+--------------+-----+-----------+
    |  2  | 2018-09-21    | Event2  | Closed  |
    |  5  | 2018-09-15    | Event5  | Closed  | 
    |  1  | 2018-09-30    | Event1  | Open    |*
    |  4  | 2018-09-30    | Event4  | Open    |*
    |  10 | 2018-10-01    | Event10 | Open    |*
    |  7  | 2018-10-15    | Event7  | Pending |*
    |  4  | 2018-10-25    | Event4  | Open    |*
    |  6  | 2018-10-25    | Event6  | Approved|*
    |  3  | 2018-12-12    | Event3  | Open    |*
    |  11 | 2018-08-25    | Event11 | Closed  |    
    |  8  | 2018-09-01    | Event8  | Closed  |
    +----+--------------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: I tried hard, but I cannot make sense of your question. I Can't figure out what you mean by "closed events that have NOT passed", any ideas I had didn't match the output you show. I also wonder why you make your SQL query missing certain parts, like the expressions and tables. I have voted to close your question because it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry didn't make myself clear and didn't want to include field names in the query for security reasons. let me see if I can edit it and more of the query.

Comment: Yes, this is a lot better, but please read, what you wrote, again: "... in which the event date is before the date of the event ...". In my experience the 'event date' is the same as the 'date of the event', and I can only find one date field in both of your tables, namely: `edates.edate`. You need two date columns to compare something. In your query you use the current date, but you have to explain how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were almost right. You need three options in your case statement - 0 for all the closed ones at the top, 2 for all the closed ones at the bottom, and 1 for everything else in the middle.  Then remove the desc on the date to get the date to be ascending inside each section, so your  order by clause should look like

```
order by (
    case when tevent.status = 'closed' and e_dates.edate >= curdate() then 0 
    when tevent.status = 'closed' and e_dates.edate < curdate() then 2
    else 1 end
), edates.edate
```

Or you could write this same thing as

```
order by (
    case when tevent.status = 'closed' 
        then case when e_dates.edate >= curdate() then 0 else 2 end
    else 1 end
), edates.edate
```